# Has the perception of time changed over the last century? (e.g. 1960's vs. now)

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, perception

How does one measure perception of time? And has it changed over the last century? My gut feeling says that people in the 50s & 60s found time to be passing slower compared to people in the present generation.

Time perception also changes as we grow older. For older people it seems to pass more quickly than for the young.

Comment: "Time perception also changes as we grow older" I know this is a colloquial fact, but do you know of research that shows this? This might also be cultural. Furthermore, how is this pertinent to your question?

Comment: Wittmann, M., & Lehnhoff, S. (2005). [Age effects in perception of time](https://doi.org/10.2466%2Fpr0.97.3.921-935). Psychological reports, 97(3), 921-935.

Comment: Anyone has any reference for the original question? Perception of time across time? Fix the age of population, how would a 30yrs old in 1960 perceive time compare to 2020? Eg. snail-mail in 2020 is in the order of days in the 1960 probably was weeks, manifacturing goods from weeks/months to  days/hours etc.